# Effect of emitter bypass capacitor

Tags: capacitor

[image]

I am studying BJT frequency response, particularly low frequency response, and I am not getting a clear picture of calculating the effect of an emitter bypass capacitor.
My question is: why is the impedance looking through capacitor not simply like this:

$$ [(R_S //(R_1//R_2)) + \beta_\text{re}] // R_E $$

Where am I going wrong in applying Thevenin's theorem for calculating Rth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where am I going wrong in applying Thevenin's theorem for calculating
>   Rth?

You're not taking into account the effect of the dependent current source on the equivalent resistance, i.e., you're treating the dependent current source as an *independent* source.

To find the equivalent impedance "seen" by the capacitor, you should use a test source, which will "activate" the dependent source.

Comment: Ok, now I am getting it.

Comment: Ok Sir, so now I will find open circuit voltage across Emitter resistor RE and find the short circuit current through emitter junction and find Rth = open circuit voltage/short circuit current.Which gives me required value of impedance.Is this correct?

Comment: @aditya, that will certainly work.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: why is the impedance looking through capacitor not simply like this: [(RS//(R1//R2))+βre]//RE ?

The impedance of the capacitor changes with the frequency of the ac signal.
Your formula is OK for dc analysis, but not for ac.

> I am studying BJT frequency response, particularly low frequency response...

So you must calculate the capacitive reactance of the capacitor with the formula Xc=1/(2πFC) where Xc is capacitive reactance, F is the frequency of the signal, and C is the capacitance of the emitter bypass capacitor in Farads.

Xc is in parallel with RE.  The effect of the emitter bypass resistor, in the circuit you have shown, is to increase the gain of the amplifier stage at all frequencies where Xc is low compared to RE.